# Inspect an image from Dockerhub without pulling the image

Tags: docker

For example I have an `Alpine` image pulled from Dockerhub. Just by using `docker pull alpine`. It was tagged with current date (let say 2019-12-12).
So now I want to update the image but first I want to check the last updated date for the `latest` or newest version before pulling it.

For local image we can just use `docker inspect alpine:latest`. Is there any API or command that can get that done?

Comment: You can use [Skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo). It is able to __inspect a remote image showing its properties including its layers, without requiring you to pull the image to the host__. Check [examples](https://github.com/containers/skopeo/blob/main/docs/skopeo-inspect.1.md#examples)

Comment: `docker pull` won't re-download any image layers you already have locally, so if you just `docker pull alpine` that will in effect check if there is a newer version and download it only if there is.  Would that meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Like David says in the comments, a `docker pull` will only pull changed layers.

```
$ docker pull alpine:latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
a0d0a0d46f8b: Already exists
Digest: sha256:e1c082e3d3c45cccac829840a25941e679c25d438cc8412c2fa221cf1a824e6a
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:latest
docker.io/library/alpine:latest

$ docker pull alpine:latest
latest: Pulling from library/alpine
Digest: sha256:e1c082e3d3c45cccac829840a25941e679c25d438cc8412c2fa221cf1a824e6a
Status: Image is up to date for alpine:latest
docker.io/library/alpine:latest
```

In fact, from the output, you can see it checking the digest of the manifest list, so I don't believe it's even pulling the manifest on the second query, it can check that with a simple head request. And as for why the first pull mentioned `a0d0a0d46f8b: Already exists`, if another image based on that Alpine image had been pulled, the underlying layer would have already been retrieved.

If you do want to check data from the registry directly without pulling the image and layers, there are a variety of tools to do that. The ones I know of include RedHat's skopeo, Googles crane (part of go-containerregistry), and I've developed a [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/) project that includes commands like `regctl`:

```
$ regctl image digest --list alpine:latest
sha256:e1c082e3d3c45cccac829840a25941e679c25d438cc8412c2fa221cf1a824e6a
```

And you can compare that against what docker sees in the image:

```
$ docker image inspect alpine:latest --format '{{.RepoDigests}}'
[alpine@sha256:e1c082e3d3c45cccac829840a25941e679c25d438cc8412c2fa221cf1a824e6a]
```

It also allows you to check the image config without downloading the layers:

```
$ regctl image config alpine:latest
{
  "created": "2021-08-27T17:19:45.758611523Z",
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "os": "linux",
  "config": {
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh"
    ]
  },
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:e2eb06d8af8218cfec8210147357a68b7e13f7c485b991c288c2d01dc228bb68"
    ]
  },
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2021-08-27T17:19:45.553092363Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:aad4290d27580cc1a094ffaf98c3ca2fc5d699fe695dfb8e6e9fac20f1129450 in / "
    },
    {
      "created": "2021-08-27T17:19:45.758611523Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD [\"/bin/sh\"]",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This explains a lot. Thanks. Bwt I'm new to docker. Is there a way to know which version is considered as `latest` for an image? I tried to pull `elasticsearch` image using `docker pull elasticsearch` but it says `Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for elasticsearch:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`
Any idea?

Comment: @MinhNg `latest` is just another tag on the registry, would have been better if they called it `default`. Not every repository pushes that tag, likely to force the user to pick a version. From regctl, you can list tags with `regctl tag ls elasticsearch` but the data isn't there from the registry to correlate multiple tags to the same image without lots of queries. Easiest for these is to check Hub directly: https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/