# Inspect docker image without pulling

Tags: docker, image, curl, docker-registry

I need to inspect docker image in the registry without pulling it locally.

To be specific, I need to get all repo tags. Equivalent of local `docker inspect some-image | jq -r '.[0].RepoTags[]'`

Even more specific, for `some-image:latest` to get its specific version tag if it has one besides "latest"

There is SO question already, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69084988/1672461). [Regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/tree/main/config) is mentioned which repeats what [official API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) is returning. At least, I've got this impression after playing with `curl`, [manifests](https://Pulling%20an%20Image%20Manifest) from one side and `regctl image [manifest|inspect|digest]` from another

There is a snippet on Medium with beautiful green background, [Inspecting docker image ...](https://medium.com/hackernoon/inspecting-docker-images-without-pulling-them-4de53d34a604). While

```bash
 curl \
    --silent \
    --header "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" \
    "http://REGISTRY_ADDRESS/v2/$image/manifests/$tag" |
    jq -r '.config.digest'
```

... just don't have `.config.digest` (even `.config`) in the result

I run it against the private repository, so HTTP API is my best bet

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we had the issue with our Nexus (container registry). And  `.config.digest` is returned, contrary to what I stated in the original question. Besides, `$image/manifests/$tag` was taking like 20-30 seconds. So, if you see this GET request taking a lot of time, it might be this issue

Other commands, like `regctl` might been affected by this Nexus issue as well

Overall, request looks like this:

```bash
registry_url="https://${user}:${password}@some.corporate.registry" &&\
image="my-team/my-repo" &&\
tag="latest" &&\
image_url=$(echo -n "${image}" | jq --slurp --raw-input --raw-output @uri) &&\
digest=$(curl --silent --header "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" "${registry_url}/v2/${image_url}/manifests/${tag}" | jq -r '.config.digest') &&\
curl --silent --location "${registry_url}/v2/${image_url}/blobs/${digest}"
```

It does not return me tags list though, but this is a part for further investigation while registry is working :)